# Refreshing the offline page

Tags: javascript, django, page-refresh, react-refresh-webpack-plugin

I have this problem for a long time and I can't figure it out by my own.

I have a project that is coded in Django. The project has some data in the SQL tables and there are some tables which are empty yet and the empty tables will be filled by the real date and time matches with the date and time which comes from SQL table.

Some how i manage this if my site is open. in the code i have a little refresher function like this;

```
// The refresher function;
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  window.setTimeout( function() {
  window.location.reload();
}, 60000);
```

It works fantastic if the site is open in the browser but I need it to work fine again if the website is not open in the browser.

Is there any way to manage that?

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve? Question is not well phrased.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't understand either.  If the site is not open, there is nothing to refresh - can you elaborate on what you are trying to do with this?

Comment: I'm imagining something like:
I want the data I entered for a certain time on my page that I developed with django to be processed into the SQL table when that time comes. If the page is open and I entered data at 19:00, it processes this data into the table when the page is open, but it does not process if the page is not open. It should update the SQL table when necessary, even when the page is not open in the browse, thnx for helping me again.

Comment: Let's say my page shows a class at 19:00 and it's just 18:59. At 19:00, if the page is open in the browser, my refresh function works at 19:00 and the necessary data is processed in my SQL table, but if my page is not open at 19:00, the data is not processed because my javascript function (refresher) I wrote only works when my page is open. I'm looking for a way to add it to my table when the time comes for this lesson even if the page is not open